# Load a layer in qgis with c++

Tags: qgis, c++

I'm trying to write a simple qgis c++ application (Linux Mint).

My goal is to 'talk' to QGis programmatically in C++. Plugins seem at first over-complicated, as all I need for now is to extract geometry info (no need for GUI).

Below the code I'm stuck with - from Python examples it seemed to be a good first shot. It simply outputs 'oh'. I'm getting the same result (!layer.isValid()) running the code from this [pdf](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.1.0_coding-compilation_guide_en.pdf), after small edits to update to qgis 2.0. Tried two .shp files - one of them in fact a bunch of files exported from qgis (.shp, .shx, .dbf..).

What would be possible causes for a non-valid layer?

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);

puts ("im alive");

QgsVectorLayer layer ("/home/koscianski/Code/qgis/shapefiles/builtups.shp", "a name I like", "ogr");

//QgsVectorLayer *layer = app.addVectorLayer ("/home/koscianski/Code/qgis/shapefiles/builtups.shp", "a name I like", "OGR");

if (layer.isValid())                          
   printf ("Found %d", (int) layer.featureCount());
else
   puts ("oh");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain output of your program and *ask a question*. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Actually, doing this in Python isn't too hard. You can use Python from the qgis interpreter or even outside of qgis without using a GUI.

Comment: Thx Jesse. The trouble is, I wanna do that in C++ (let's, please, put aside the discussion on the why, that's another matter). By surfing around I know I bet other people has the same question: the "QGis Coding and Compilation Guide" has not been updated; no blogs, no clues. So I asked here.

Comment: People, ok if you feel this is off-topic but... at stackoverflow, the guys asks to make qgis development questions... [here!] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641888/qgis-2-4-c-helloworld). That makes perfect sense to me. There are a dozen or so similar (=development) questions around this forum. Anyway, thanks for the answers (@Jesse, @ndawson) and, truly, thnx admins for your time, it's not easy to manage a site. Ah, so far no luck (thnx @ndawson).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the QGIS application. Try replacing

```
QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
```

with

```
QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
QgsApplication::initQgis();
```

The initQgis step is required to properly initialize the provider registry, without which there will be no supported data formats.